# importing a class object from one file in to another file

Tags: python-2.7, class, python-import

I am trying to call a function in class A from  One.py file in to Two.py file by using

```
 from one import A
```

in this class A :in  **init** function i am assigning a variable name i.e; self._fname=name.
Now  i am trying to call a function funC()  from class A which uses the self._fname varible  like below in Two.py

```
 now=A()
 now.funC()
```

when call this function i am getting an **Attribute Error :Class A has no attribute '_fname'**

```
func():
if self._fname:
    print "found"
```

How can i resolve this problem.Is there any way that i can import Class A object from one.py to Two.py so by using that object i can access the 'fname' variable.

Comment: Please show actual code with the actual problem. The code snippets and the error message don't match.  You show the call of `funC` but the (incomplete) definition of `func()`, `func()` accesses the attribute `fname` but the error message refers to `_fname`. It's hard to help here.

Comment: You've changed the attribute name in the code now but still haven't shown the actual code. Show enough code to enable us to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 0):

AttributeError are typically raised when you try to access an attribute or member which is not defined in the object being dealt with. In your case,
you are initializing self._fname and are trying to use self.fname, which in my opinion is not defined in your class 'A' (notice the underscore before 'fname') . so basically, if you try to access the correct member (self._fname) in func() ,your Attribute error would go away !